# Install package from npm after linking to another local package with updated version

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-link

I'm sure others have this workflow, so I must be missing something here.

How does one go about developing a new version of a package, linking it to test in another app, and then installing another (unrelated) package?

What I've done:

1. Run `git clone git@package-to-update && cd package-to-update`.
2. Edit package, update `package-to-update/package.json` version to `2.0.0`.
3. Update `my-app/package.json` to use `package-to-update@2.0.0`.
4. `cd package-to-update && npm link && cd my-appp && npm link package-to-update`.
5. Test out `my-app`, see that `package-to-update@2.0.0` resolves the issue, have a small party.
6. Push to `package-to-update`'s upstream, create a merge request, and wait for maintainers to merge in my changes.
7. Use my local, linked version in the meantime as it's required for the feature I'm working on.
8. Notice I need another package `other-unrelated-package` in `my-app`.
9. Run `cd my-app && npm install other-unrelated-package`.
10. NPM fails because it's trying to pull `package-to-update@2.0.0`, which is not yet published.
11. Cry.

Is the only option here to run the following process every time you want to `npm install`?

1. Downgrade `package-to-update` in `my-app/package.json`.
2. Run `npm install other-package`.
3. Run `npm link package-to-update`.
4. Upgrade `package-to-update` in `my-app/package.json`".

Answer (score 0):

I generally only use `npm link` for development. If I want to use a local version and not have to deal with re-linking, I install it by path rather than by version.

```
npm install /file/path/to/your/module
```

Then you'll end up with a `file:` URL like this in your `package.json`:

```json
    "slug": "file:../../slug"
```

Subsequent `npm install` won't search the registry in that case. (Since it will avoid the registry on future `npm install` runs, it also means you need to remember to change it back to the registry when the version with your patch is released!)

I haven't tested, but this method may require that you only care about it as an immediate dependency and not a dependency of another dependency. Based on your workflow above, that seems to be the case, but mentioning it here for other folks.

Comment: But I don't want to rely on my local version permanently, I just want to use it during development. When my feature is done, I'd like to mark the merge request as WIP until the upstream repository accepts and merges my changes and we can use the official, updated package in CI.